# Finding a set in Borel sigma algebra given a set in Lebesgue measurable space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is an exercise question in my Lebesgue Integration course. I feel like I should make use of collection of closed sets but I have no idea where to start.

Here is the question:

Let $E\in M$ be such that $\mu(E)$ = $0$. Show that there is a $B$ in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $E\subset B$ and $\mu(B) = 0$.

Here $(\mathbb{R}, M, \mu)$ is Lebesgue measurable space.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E$ is measurable, we know that $0 = \mu(E) = \mu^* (E) = \inf m^*(U)$ where $U$ is an open set containing $E$. Thus, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an open $U \supset E$ such that $\mu(U) < \epsilon$. Thus, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is an open $O_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $E \subset O_n$ and $\mu (O_n) < \frac{1}{n}$.

Now take the following set: $$O = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty O_n$$

$O$ is a $G_\delta$ set, and hence is a Borel set. Additionally, $O$ contains $E$ and has measure $0$.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that we can find such a measurable sequence of open sets require proof as well? After that point on, I follow the proof but that part is not obvious to me. Maybe I can use $\mu(E)$ = $inf \mu(O)$ but I can't see how.

Comment: I am making an appeal to property 9 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure. If you have not proven this statement, it is worth noting that it is equivalent to the Carotheodory Condition.

Comment: Actually, that's more machinery than is even necessary. Let me edit the post and make it more clear

Comment: Knowing that property, rest of the proof is understandable to me. However I am still trying to figure out a way to prove property 9.

Comment: Since $E$ is a nullset, property 9 isn't necessary. See my edit.

Comment: @Polygebra If you want to prove property 9, consider the following. Recall that a set $E$ is Lebesgue measurable iff for any $S$, we have $$\mu^* (S) = \mu^*(S \cap E) + \mu^*(S \cap E^c)$$. Take open $O \supset E$ such that $\mu(O) - \mu(E) < \epsilon$. Applying the above to $O$, since $E$ is measurable, gives $$\mu^*(O) = \mu^*(O \cap E) + \mu^*(O \cap E^c)$$ But $O \cap E = E$ and $O \cap E^c = O \setminus E$. Thus $$\mu(O) = \mu(E) + \mu^* (O \setminus E)$$, which implies $$\mu(O \setminus E) < \epsilon$$.

Comment: Thank you, I was just trying this but I have a question. How can we guarantee the existence of such an open set? Also how did you get rid of $\mu^*$ as you finish the proof?

Comment: @Polygebra We are guaranteed the open set with that property by the exact same reasoning as in my answer above. To get rid of the $\mu^*$, since Lebesgue measurable sets form a sigma-algebra, we have for any $E,F \in \mathcal{M}$ that $E \cap F^c = E \setminus F$ is measurable as well. I simply applied this to $O$ and $E$ above, and used that for a measurable set, outer measure and measure align.

Comment: I see it now, thank you for your time.